# Accidental Windows restart during file transfer

Tags: windows, windows-10

I accidentally restarted (using the shutdown/restart option in start menu) my Windows 10 computer while the it was still moving files from one drive to another. I was moving folders containing multiple files. I think I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> from the GUI.

Should I worry about missing/corrupt files?

Can I assume the shutdown/restart function in windows is smart enough to gracefully cancel the file transfer operation?

Comment: What type of file transfer command?  Be specific Windows handles moving a file, copying a file, and cutting and pasting a file differently.  You should edit your question.

Comment: @ramhound see update

Comment: So you cut and pasted the file.  If that’s the case the file isn’t moved until the entire file is completed.

Comment: is windows smart enough to delete the partially copied file when the restart happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A move between drives is actually a copy followed by a delete. Your original file should remain until the copy is completed.

Note that this applies per-file, so if you are moving multiple files then some files will be completely moved (and therefore the original deleted) while others will be completely unmoved (so only the original exists).

Additionally, the file you are *currently* moving might have a partial copy on the destination drive. This really depends on how graceful the shutdown was - if the transfer was interrupted gracefully (e.g. by clicking cancel), it will delete the partial copy. Unfortunately, it appears that the normal shutdown/restart process does *not* gracefully interrupt the transfer, so you *do* end up with the partial file.

Note that because the full file size is allocated at the beginning of the transfer, any interrupted partial files will look like the full size - but the data won't match.

---

All you really need to do now is attempt the move again, and *overwrite* any duplicates/conflicts (since the original should still be the full file while the target might be a partial file). If you wish to move files back in the other direction, you should do the opposite and *keep* the original while ignoring any duplicates.

Comment: I was moving multiple folders / files

Comment: @James The second and third paragraphs address that.

Comment: restarting the computer from the start menu should be ok right? ( = graceful shutdown)

Comment: @James I would have thought so, but unfortunately that appears to not be the case (based on a little testing). So you'll probably end up with a partial file (despite reporting the full file size) on the destination. In any case, the fix is simple: perform the same transfer and overwrite existing files when prompted.